# Save Spring XML Configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

Forgive me if this has been answered before ...

I want to load a spring configuration xml file from disk, have the user modify settings, then save the modifications back to the xml file, for initialization during a subsequent run of the application.

For instance, say a class has a collection of classes, each with their own bean configurations. Through the UI, the user may reconfigure any of the sub-classes and/or add/remove any sub-classes from the collection.

Example application-context.xml:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="mainClass" class="...">
    <property name="subClassList">
      <list>
        <ref bean="subClassA" />
        <ref bean="subClassB" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="subClassA" class="...">
    <property name="var1" value="1" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="subClassB" class="...">
    <property name="var2" value="100" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

So, not only do I want to allow the user to modify var1 & var2 in the application and save the configuration, but the user could remove subClassB from the list or add subClassC to the list, within the application, then save the configuration.

Also, the application is a desktop app, not web-based. In addition, "mainClass" is not the class that contains the application entry point, "main()". Think of "mainClass" as a container, with a collection of other classes, each of which has a "process()". So, the parent class, mainClass, iterates through each subClass, runs process(), then evaluates what the overall result will be. Adding subclasses and modifying subClass parameters, then saving the configuration is the goal.

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: Sounds like a text editor to me.  Users should not be permitted to perform such changes.  Application configuration is for all users, not just one.  How would you handle multiple users accessing the config at the same time?  What about conflicting changes?  You should rethink this.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Good points. Beans are prototypes. After customization, xml files are saved to "user" space only seen by specific user. Config files could be read from "static" area, customized, then saved to "user" area.

Comment: Also need to mention that this application is NOT web-based.

Comment: Have you considered Spring Boot? application-context.xml is unnecessary then and you don't have to deal with such tedious bean management.

Comment: Just added more info. This is not web-based. Isn't spring-boot for web apps? It's actually JavaFX-based using spring framework to load/use beans. The loading and execution is all fine. Just want to modify the spring context and write it out. Dynamic configuration of the app without the user (non-java dev) editing the spring context xml file.

Comment: If spring framework cannot handle this, that's fine, I'll write it myself. Thought the spring framework would be able to handle this or at least get me most of the way there.